# Solve y'+y = -x/y

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y' + y = \frac{-x}{y}$$

As far as I'm aware, this should be a Bernoulli Equation.

When I attempt to solve it, I transform it into $y' + \frac{x}{y} = -y$

I let $V= y^{1-n}$, where $n = 1$. The derivative of this is $V' = (1-n) y^{-n} y'$, but this gives $V' = 0$. Additionally, when I try to make it so that it is in the form $y' = $, it is undefined.

How is this supposed to be solved? If there's another way to solve it, I'd be okay with that too.

Comment: It is not transformable in the form $y'+Py=Qy^n$ where $P,Q$ are functions of $x$. Why do you think it is Bernoulli?

Comment: @Shahab, wouldn't the $P$ function be $x$ and the $Q$ function be $x^0$?

Comment: You need $Py$ term whereas what you have is the $P/y$ term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The given differential equation is transformable to $(x+y^2)dx+ydy=0$. Multiplying both sides by $e^{2x}$ will make it an exact differential equation:
$$e^{2x}(x+y^2)dx+ye^{2x}dy=0$$

A general rule regarding equations of the form $Mdx+Ndy=0$ is that if $$\frac{1}{N}\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}\right)$$ is solely a function of $x$, say $f(x)$, then multiplication by $$\exp\left(\int f(x)dx\right)$$ will change the problem into an exact differential equation.

Comment: Why the factor $e^{2x}$?

Comment: @Did: It is easy to prove (armed with hindsight) that for $Mdx+Ndy=0$ if $\frac{M_y-Nx}{N}=f(x)$ then $exp(\int f(x)dx)$ is an integrating factor.

Comment: This element of method might be the most interesting part of the solution. You might wish to include it in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

( comes down to choosing $n=-1$ )

$$y' + y = \frac{-x}{y} \implies yy' + y^2=-x$$
let $u=y^2$  so that $u'=2y'y$

in terms of $u$ ...

$$\frac 12 u' + u = -x$$

which you can solve